# How to pass additional parameters to trait's Display or debug implementation?

Tags: rust, string-formatting

I have an interpreter written in Rust which parses the passed script and represents that as nested tree of structs and enums. All these structs and enums implement `Debug` trait, so I am able to nicely print them. The only issue is with one particular struct, shown below.

```
struct Meta {
    start_index: usize,
    end_index: usize,
}
```

The above struct is contained by almost all nodes in the tree. The indices represent the start and end indices in the script String.

During the `Debug` print of `Meta` I would like print string slice represented by those bounds instead of those numbers. However, neither `Meta` nor any node in the tree have reference to the actual passed script string. So, even if I implement the `Debug` trait, since I don't have access to the passed string it won't help.

I don't want to add a string field to Meta as this requirement is only for debug and test purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea that may work: create an additional `struct` that includes a borrowed `Meta` along with your source `String` (borrowed as well). It might look like this:

```
struct MetaWithSource<'a> {
  meta: &'a Meta,
  source: &'a str
}
```

Now, implement `Debug`/`Display` for `MetaWithSource`:

```
use std::fmt;

impl<'a> fmt::Debug for MetaWithSource<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        // We now have access to the source via `self.source`
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Lastly, we can add a method on `Meta` to give us a `MetaWithSource`:

```
impl Meta {
    pub fn with_source<'a>(&'a self, source: &'a str) -> MetaWithSource<'a> {
        MetaWithSource {
            meta: self,
            source,
        }
    }
}
```

What does that buy us? We can now print `Meta`s using `{:?}` like so:

```
let m: Meta = ...
println!("{:?}", m.with_source(src));

// Since `m` is only borrowed by `with_source`, we can still use it here
```

The downside is that we need to create an additional struct `FooWithSource` for each struct `Foo` that needs to display part of the source string (even if they don't use the source string directly!). This may or may not be a huge pain.

Unfortunately, unless the source string is somehow included in the objects that refer to it (like `Meta`), I can't see any way around this last problem. One fix here (which I'm sure you've considered) is to simply include the source string or a slice alongside the other information in `Meta`:

```
struct Meta {
    start_index: usize,
    end_index: usize,
    text: String,
}
```

or

```
struct Meta<'a> {
    start_index: usize,
    end_index: usize,
    text: &'a str
}
```

Neither of these is a perfect solution: the first one allocates a new `String`, even though you probably don't ever need the full power of ownership; the second is "infected" with the source string's lifetime, and will therefore "infect" any other struct that contains it.

Even though it allocates, I anticipate the first one will be much more pleasant to work with. If you're worried about the allocation (especially if you're storing a lot of "concrete" syntax like "(", whitespace, etc.), you can use an "interner" and store an `Rc<String>` instead, where multiple instances of the same text will simply share pointers (and won't require a new `String` allocation). Here's a quick sketch of what that might look like:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Meta {
    start_index: usize,
    end_index: usize,
    text: Rc<String>,
}

struct Interner<'a> {
    seen: HashMap<&'a str, Rc<String>>,
}


impl<'a> Interner<'a> {
    pub fn intern(&mut self, text: &'a str) -> Rc<String> {
        // Copies a pointer to a `String` referring to the text if we've already seen it:
        self.seen.get(text).map(Rc::clone).unwrap_or_else(|| {
            // Only allocates a new `String` if we haven't seen it yet:
            let new = Rc::new(String::from(text));
            self.seen.insert(text, Rc::clone(&new));
            new
        })
    }
}
```

Then, assuming you construct `Meta`s inside a lexer of some kind, you'll need to add an `Interner<'a>` to your lexer. Wherever you create new `Meta`s, just call `lexer.interner.intern(&lexer.src[start_index..end_index])` to get an `Rc<String>`.

Comment: Yes I actually ended up implementing `with_source` kind of scheme. However I did not create a new `MetaWithSource` rather I have a `HasMeta` trait which all structs with `Meta` in them implement, so I added `with_source` kind of method there. It was quite arduous. Later when implementing interpreter which has access only to the AST I reached the same problem. So I have now also a `text: Rc<String>` to `Meta`. So now I have both kind of implementations!

Answer (score -1):

Implement proper debug information for `Meta`, where it is applicable. For example, if struct `X` knows everything about `Meta` and about required string slice, then it should be there.

Shall `Meta` implement `Debug` on themself? It depends, if that data is valuable for anyone without those string slices. If not, then it has no sense